# Changing cell color when there is a price change in the matrix for that month

Tags: excel, matrix, reference, formatting, conditional-statements

I want my cells to change without having to do conditional formatting and then pasting the format painter to each cell. Let's say I have a matrix with 999,999 cells in the sheet right now.

For this example, let's say we have months in the rows (ROW 1), and bananas, apples, and oranges in the columns (COLUMN A). In the matrix are the prices.

How would we be able to do something that would automatically COLOR A CELL RED if there was a price change from the previous month to the current month? Also is there an automatic way to color the cells green if the price goes down and red if the price goes up?

Comment: **Post a picture of your current setup**

Answer (score 1):

You can create rules that can extend to a range without using the painter.

I'm assuming that the months are ordered. Procedure to paint RED:

1 - Choose one cell with one value to compare, let's use C3 as an example.

2 - Go to Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules

3 - In the window, create new rule

4 - Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

5 - In the textbox below, enter the formula =IF(C3>C2;1;0) (Depending on your settings, ";" might be ","

6 - Press Format and adjust the cell format as needed, press OK

7 - Press OK

8 - You have the first rule. Now, in the textbox "Applies to" you need to put the full range of your matrix (ex: =$C$3:$D$99999)

9 - Press Apply

10 - Create a new rule for the green